# ExtJS buttons won't accept "id" config parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I need specific IDs on ExtJS generated window buttons, but I'm having trouble specifying the ID. The [documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/output/Ext.Button.html) claims that this should be possible, but I still get an autogenerated id when I specify my own.

What gives?

```
dialog = new Ext.Window({
            closeAction:'hide',
            plain: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    id: 'my-dialog',
                    text: 'Done',
                    handler: function() {
                        dialog.hide();
                    }
                }
            ],
            items:new Ext.Panel({
                applyTo:'add-document-popup-panel'
            }),
            title: 'Add Documents',
            layout: 'fit',
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            modal: true
        });
    }
    dialog.show(this);
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you pass `buttons` as an array of `Ext.Button` rather than an array of `Ext.Button` configuration objects?

Comment: Did you try putting quotes (using `'id'` instead of `id`) ? (I has once a problem with something like this)

Comment: are you searching this id in html, right? I've tried and got this html `<table id="my-dialog" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn x-btn-noicon" style="width: 75px; "> ...`

Comment: You don't elaborate on why this is an issue, so it's not really possible to suggest anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this topic: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?24433-CLOSED-Cannot-assign-id-to-button-extjs-bug

The id of the **container** of the button is set, not the HTML button itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I found this out myself before you posted, but yup, this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The `id` you specify is assigned to the button component (specific to extjs) and not necessarily to the underlying html button.

Does `Ext.getCmp('my-dialog')` successfully return the extjs button component?

Answer (score 0):

The ID is set, but not on the actual button element. One of the containers is set with the correct id, and you can probably key off of this to get at whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I confirm:

- The ID is set in the button's TABLE container.
- Ext.getCmp('my-button') returns the extjs button component (object with xtype="button" and id="my-button").